# How to get a Finish Later email reminder?

Tags: docusignapi

In Docusign, we are using the SOAP API and there is an option when signing a document to finish later yet when doing so, no email is sent in order to finish later.
Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Finish Later does not trigger a new email to the signer.  It saves any data entry (but not Signatures or Initials) and exits.  The signer can use their initial email to go back to finish signing at any time before the expiration period is met.

If you are using this in an Embedded scenario within your own web application but still want the signer to get an email make sure the "Suppress Emails to Embedded Signers" option is NOT checked under Preferences -> Features.  This way when Finish Later routes back to your web application you could then display a message saying, "Since you chose not to complete signing at this time, please follow the link in the email you received when you are ready to sign".